# TS2307: Cannot find module '****' or its corresponding type declarations - Angular 16

Tags: angular

For a strange reason my project is unable to resolve my custom angualr 16 libraries.

Sample:

````
import { DemoLibraryModule } from 'demo002-library'; // Here I get the TS2307 error

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DemoLibraryModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }```

The ts cannot identify the demo002-library import but if i use demo002-library/src/public.api it seems to be ok.

I have tried to rebuild, republish and install - unistall my package but typescript still cannot find the module.
````

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig files for you library project?  if you created the library with the angular CLI, it should have added a section called paths for you where it automatically mapped your public_api file to an alias like '@demo002-library'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

I missed the 'cd dist/demo002-library' command.

I was running 'npm publish' not from inside dist folder and the index.d.ts was never published!!!

The answer is here:
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

1. ng build my-lib
2. cd dist/my-lib
3. npm publish